# Dart Split list into sublists based on a value of a certain property?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, grouping

I have a list of events which has a DateTime property and i want to make sublists of this list based on year.
Is there a way that I can split my main list of events into sublists so that within each sublist, each event has the same year? So I would end up with a sublist of all 2020 events, a sublist of all 2021 events, and so on.

`List<DayTasks>` where DayTasks is defined as:

```
class DayTasks{
  List<Task> _tasks = [];

  final DateTime _date;
}
```

`List<Task>` is not a concern here, i want to perform this for `List<DayTasks>`.

Comment: check [grupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) to get sub list based on year of date. Lets assume you have a list of DayTasks as

```
final dayTaskList = <DayTasks>[];
```

you can fetch the grouped list of DayTasks based on same year using this:

```
final groupedList = groupBy(dayTaskList, (DayTasks dayTasks) => DateTime(dayTasks._date.year)).entries.toList();
```

This grouped list can be used to iterate throught the sublistd created.